# Error 503 attempting an HTTPS request using python-requests

Tags: python, https, python-requests

This is probably very simple but for some reason I fail to do it properly.
I have an internal HTTPS service I'd like to access and fetch the HTML content for further processing. 
Inside any browser it works fine but when attempting to run the code I am getting a 503 error from the server and incorrect HTML content.
Here's my code:

```
import pytest
import requests


def test_basic():
    """
    Some comment
        """
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    hostname = 'https://some_address'
    page = requests.get(hostname, headers = headers, verify=False)
    html_contents = page.text
    print(html_contents)
```

I tried spoofing the user agent and passed verify=False to avoid any SSL issue but I still get the following error:

503. reason: 'Service Unavailable'
     Thanks!

Comment: Your code works for me when requesting `https://google.com`. Does it work for you if you specify a different website? Does the website you're trying to fetch work in a browser?

Comment: Works fine in the browser.. https://google.com works fine as well

Comment: What is the `hostname` you are actually using?

Comment: It's an internal web service, based on Hawkular - http://www.hawkular.org/

Comment: Can you show the requests made in chrome tools?

Comment: Like this? http://imgur.com/a/qyi6B

Comment: I would need to see the headers etc,, for the status and metrics